# Import java package com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig using python with py4j

Tags: java, python, pyspark, jvm, py4j

I can import all from `java.*` using the jvm from JavaGateway of py4j

for example:

```
jvm.java.util.ArrayList
jvm.java.lang.System
random = jvm.java.util.Random()
random.nextInt(3)
```

or in this form:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(jvm,'java.util.*')
random = jvm.Random()
random.nextInt(3)
```

I need to import:

```
com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig
com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
com.typesafe.config.Config
```

But it doesn't work, I tried these ways:

```
jvm.com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig
jvm.java.com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig
jvm.java.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig
java_import(jvm,'com.typesafe.config.*')
java_import(jvm,'com.typesafe.config.impl.*')
jvm.SimpleConfig
jvm.impl.SimpleConfig
```

all returns: `py4j.java_gateway.JavaPackage`
not `py4j.java_gateway.JavaClass`  as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to download the JAR
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/1.4.1/config-1.4.1.jar
then add the JAR in the `("spark.jars", jar_path)`